# Delphi and Google-Chrome WebBrowser

Tags: google-chrome, delphi, firemonkey

In my Delphi/Firemonkey desktop application I would like to include a Google-chrome viewer with the extension installed.
Is it possible?

Requirements:

1. Delphi 10.4
2. Google Chrome version - 84.0.4147.105 (64-bit)  and above
3. Windows 10

Comment: Please add a minumum of Information, like what version of Delphi do you use? In the newest version the TwebBrowser componentn is updated and can use the Chromium component from something like EDGE browser. I dont know what it looks like when developing for Android or iOS but if there are no more Informations, there will be no Help.

Comment: This is supposed to be a Windows desktop application. Probably only in the destop version you can upload extensions to the browser

Comment: I'm don't quite understand "with the extension installed". *What* extension? Or did you mean to say "win *an* extension installed"?

Comment: I need to have a active chrome extension like:  https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/shared_contacts_for_gmail%C2%AE/1033860418004

Comment: The browser component in Delphi 10.4 is a Chromium engine - not a Chrome Browser. So probably no. Firefox and Edge use Chromium engine but you cant load Chrome extensions into them can you?

Comment: The extension works only under Google- Chrome Browser

Comment: CEF4Delphi has a very limited extension support. The number of supported extension APIs is small and that extension may use some unsupported calls. I would suggest that you try to translate the code in that extension to Delphi using the CEF API directly, if possible.